# Query about how to pass vector by reference to a constructor

Tags: c++

I am currently learning c++ and was trying to write code that will find the minima of a function. I have put my starting points in vectors `p0`,`p1`,`p2` and stored those set of points in a vector which I have called `pmatrix`.

I am trying to pass this `pmatrix` as an argument when I am creating an object of the simplex class. When I wrote the code below my hope was that I had correctly passed the `pmatrix`, by reference, into the constructor properly as no errors came up.

However, after calling the evaluate method which changes `pmatrix`, printing the values inside and outside of the class definition, it has not changed in the main scope and somewhere 2 separate copies of `pmatrix` exist. How do I make sure that the changes the methods do to `pmatrix` act on the one I have defined in the main scope?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Simplex {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> pmatrix;
    double (*F)(double x_0,double x_1);

    public:
        Simplex(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &pmatrix,double (*func)(double,double)){
            this->pmatrix = pmatrix;
            F=func;
        }

        void evaluate(){
           for (int i=0; i<pmatrix.size();i++){
               std::vector<double> p_i;
               p_i=pmatrix[i];
               p_i[p_i.size()-1]=F(p_i[0],p_i[1]);
               pmatrix[i]=p_i;


            }
        }
        void test(){
            std::cout<<"pmatrix[i][2] elements inside the class def is "<<pmatrix[0][2]<<" "<<pmatrix[1][2]<<" "<<pmatrix[2][2]<<"\n";




        }

};
//defining rosenbrocks parabolic valley
double rpv (double x1, double x0){
    return 100*(x0-(x1*x1))*(x0-(x1*x1))+(1-x0)*(1-x0);
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> p0 = {0,0,1};
    std::vector<double> p1 = {2,0,2};
    std::vector<double> p2 = {0,2,3};
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> pmatrix = {p0,p1,p2};

    Simplex simplex(pmatrix,rpv);
    simplex.evaluate();

    std::cout<<"pmatrix[i][2] elements from pmatrix in main "<<pmatrix[0][2]<<" "<<pmatrix[1][2]<<" "<<pmatrix[2][2]<<"\n";
    simplex.test();



return 1;
}
```

output

```
pmatrix[i][2] elements from pmatrix in main 1 2 3
pmatrix[i][2] elements inside the class def is 1 1601 401
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: if your points have 3 coordinates then consider creating a `struct Point { int x, y, z; }` and then have `std::vector<Point>`.

Comment: Apart from readability, is there any benefit to doing so?

Comment: @V.Jain Readability is an important part of your code. Keep it simple, and whenever you can combine such things into a struct, it is a good idea to do so.

Comment: @V.Jain Also, you can using the following statement: `using PointsMatrix = std::vector<Point>` to make it even tidier!

Comment: @Kerek I don't recommend that. Why is `Point.push_back()`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @V.Jain yes, readability is **extremely** important. Also there is definitely a performance benefit as well.

Comment: @bolov I would suggest using std::array if possible, but it seems that he is just looking for a list of points.

Comment: @bolov Also, Point is a struct of 3 doubles, you are talking about PointsMatrix (In the code I have put, I rewrote it to `PointsList` which is more suitable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Simplex::pmatrix` a reference, and initialize it in your constructor's member initializer list. References need to be assigned their referent on construction, so by the time you're in the body of your constructor it's too late; all members have been default constructed already.

That's what the member initializer list is for. You should get into the habit of using it even when not forced in situations like these.

```
class Simplex {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>& pmatrix; // <-- this is a ref now
    double (*F)(double x_0,double x_1);

    public:
        Simplex(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &otherpmatrix,
                double (*func)(double,double))
        : pmatrix(otherpmatrix)
        , F(func)
        { }

    // other various Simplex things...
}
```

This should be fine as long as you manage the lifetimes of `Simplex` and `pmatrix` and ensure that `pmatrix` isn't destroyed before `Simplex`.

Comment: Can you clarify on your syntax, I tried to change my simplex class as you suggested by changing the line:
`std::vector<std::vector<double>> pmatrix;`
to 
`std::vector<std::vector<double>> &pmatrix;`


`Simplex(std::vector<std::vector<double>> pmatrix,double (*func)(double,double))` to 
`Simplex(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &otherpmatrix,double (*func)(double,double))`


and 
`this->pmatrix=pmatrix;` to `this->pmatrix=otherpmatrix;`.


This gives me an error.

Comment: I appreciate that comment is difficult to read, if you could edit your answer so that I can compile the code with error I would appreciate it.

Comment: What error did you get? Note that I'm using an initialization list (the stuff between `:` and `{` after the function parameters.

Comment: The name change to `otherpmatrix` was just so I could keep the member variable and parameter separate in my head. I don't like function parameters having the same name as member variables. Feel free to keep it as `pmatrix` if you like.

Comment: I also just removed the `this->` from the initialization list. I think that was an error.

Comment: I have never used that syntax before so I was copying it wrong. I copy and pasted without changing anything and it worked. What is list initialisation?

Comment: Sorry it's called an initializer list, not initialization. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: I understand this, but i dont think i fully get why my code doesn't work. When I assign the pmatrix defined in the class by reference in the constructor, why doesn't the pmatrix in simplex automatically point to the same pmatrix in main as is normally the case when you pass by reference?

Comment: Because only a reference can reference another variable. Your `pmatrix` wasn't originally a reference. It was a `pmatrix`. A `pmatrix` can't reference a `pmatrix`. Only a `pmatrix&` can reference a `pmatrix`. The other option is to to have your `Simplex` be responsible for constructing the `pmatrix`, and then you can pull a reference to it in your main. But the original needs to be somewhere. They can't both be `pmatrix` and they can't both be `pmatrix&`.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on who is the ***owner*** of `pmatrix`. If it only uses `pmatrix`, I would use:

`std::vector<Point>& pmatrix;`

And pass it as reference in the ctor. It is also possible to keep it as a ***pointer***, which means that it can be `nullptr`, and we **don't** own it.

On the case where there is no one **true** owner, and it should be shared, you should use `std::shared_ptr` which means that it won't be destroyed while in use in the `Simplex`:

```
struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

using PointList = std::vector<Point>;

using FunctionPtr = double(*)(double, double);

class Simplex 
{
    std::shared_ptr<PointList> pmatrix;
    FunctionPtr F; // find a better name for it!

public:
    Simplex(const std::shared_ptr<PointList>& otherpmatrix,
            FunctionPtr func) : 
        pmatrix(otherpmatrix), 
        F(func)
    {
    }
};

double rpv (double x1, double x0){
    return 100*(x0-(x1*x1))*(x0-(x1*x1))+(1-x0)*(1-x0);
}

int main()
{
    auto pmatrix = std::shared_ptr<PointList>(new PointList());
    pmatrix->push_back({0,0,1});
    pmatrix->push_back({2,0,2});
    pmatrix->push_back({0,2,3});

    Simplex simplex(pmatrix, &rpv);
}
```

This denotes that you have a shared ownership of this object.

Comment: What error? [You can check it, it compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Bztjkr)